# mysql query login in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication, permissions

I'm creating a simple login (User, password and level of power; 1-Normal user  2-Admin)

So, my table only have 4 columns  (ID, user, password and lvl). I already have the query to enter in the login, the thing that I want is to create a "if"/condition to open a Form. For example, if you enter your information and you are a normal user the form "Normal_user" shows, but if you're an admin the form "Admin" shows. My actual code without the level of permission is:

```
try
        {
            MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=SOIS; UID=root; Pwd=; ");
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from usuarios where empleado_id = '" + username.Text + "'  and password = '" + password.Password + "'", c);
              MySqlDataReader lectura;
              c.Open();
              lectura = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              int count = 0;
              while (lectura.Read()) {
                  count = count + 1;
              }
              if (count == 1)
              {
                  MainWindow win2 = new MainWindow();
                  win2.Show();
                  c.Close();     //In this part I think can add another query and put it into an if
                  this.Close();
              }
              else
              {
                  c.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong information");
            }

            c.Close();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please note that your code is extremely prone to the threat of [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Please use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead! Additionally you seem to store your passwords in plain text which is an absolute no go. Please, even if this is just a test project for learning purposes, change that!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll investigate and make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a 4th column in your database to identify admin user.

```
try
        {
            MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=SOIS; UID=root; Pwd=; ");
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from usuarios where empleado_id = '" + username.Text + "'  and password = '" + password.Password + "'", c);
              MySqlDataReader lectura;
              c.Open();
              lectura = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              int count = 0;
              bool isAdmin = false;
              while (lectura.Read()) {
                  count = count + 1;
                  isAdmin = (lecture[3] == 1) ? true : false;
              }
              if (count == 1)
              {
                  MainWindow win2 = new MainWindow();
                  win2.Show();
                  if( isAdmin ) {
                      // if admin open admin form
                  }
                  c.Close();     //In this part I think can add another query and put it into an if
                  this.Close();
              }
              else
              {
                  c.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong information");
            }

            c.Close();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, just had to modify this line:   isAdmin = (lectura[3].Equals( 1)) ? true : false;